# install language in texlive - hyphenation

Tags: latex

I am a latex beginner so forgive this basic question: How do I activate danish hyphenation in latex?

Output from the latest file below:

thanks in advance

> This is pdfTeXk, Version
>   3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)  %&-line parsing enabled. entering extended
>   mode (./rks_prognose_metode.tex
>   LaTeX2e <2005/12/01> Babel  and
>   hyphenation patterns for english,
>   usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
>   yphenation, loaded.
>   (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
>   Document Class: article 2005/09/16
>   v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
>   (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
>   (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
>   (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/danish.ldf
>   (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)
>
> Package babel Warning: No hyphenation
>   patterns were loaded for (babel)
>   the language `Danish' (babel)
>   I will use the patterns loaded for
>   \language=0 instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try the following (tested on Ubuntu 9.04)

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-european
sudo texhash
sudo fmtutil --all
```

Comment: Hi rcs - thanks a lot. install of texlive did it. I have not yet done a sudo texhash or fmtutil - as that doesn't seem to be nescessary. Why did you suggest it?

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the relevant code?

This piece of latex should work:

```
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
```

If not, there is a problem with you installation.

Comment: I initially just did a apt-get install texlive. And everything else works fine. My preamble looks like this (so yes I call babel):

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figur}
\begin{document}

Comment: Taking a extra look at your output it looks like babel don't have danish installed.

I don't know much about debian/ubuntu packaging but package.debian.org says you might need to install texlive-lang-danish. Try that.